# Implementing a transformation as $UaU$ and not $UaU^{-1}$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, symmetry, operators, parity

I know one associates to each symmetry transformation a unitary/antiunitary operater...etc.

But equation 3.123 in Peskin and Schroeder (PS) says that parity is implemented as $(\mathbf{p}$ is the three momentum)

$$P a_{\mathbf{p}}^sP = \eta_a a_{\mathbf{-p}}^s \tag{1}, $$
where $P$ is the operator implementing the parity transformation.

My question is why the left hand side of $(1)$ not of the form $PaP^{-1}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Parity operator is its own inverse: $P^{-1} = P$.

See, for example, [this set of lecture notes](http://www.pa.msu.edu/~mmoore/Lect21_Parity.pdf).

Comment: Yes that's true, but I think that PS should mention that they have used that property. It comes out of the blue (if I haven't missed anything?) I'm ranting but sometimes that book gets on my nerves I guess.

Comment: I haven't used PS myself, but I see many texts skipping steps like this that the author thinks is too trivial to bother writing. I agree that this particular step should be included.